# Create grouping variable for consecutive sequences and split vector

Tags: r, vector, sequence, data-partitioning

I have a vector, such as `c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 17, 29, 30)` and I would like to group together the 'neighboring' elements that form a regular, consecutive sequence, i.e. an increase by 1, in a ragged vector resulting in:

L1: 1
L2: 3,4,5
L3: 9,10
L4: 17
L5: 29,30

Naive code (of an ex-C programmer):

```
partition.neighbors <- function(v)
{
    result <<- list() #jagged array
    currentList <<- v[1] #current series

    for(i in 2:length(v))
    {
        if(v[i] - v [i-1] == 1)
        {
            currentList <<- c(currentList, v[i])
        }
        else
        {
            result <<- c(result, list(currentList))
            currentList <<- v[i] #next series
        }       
    }

    return(result)  
}
```

Now I understand that
 a) R is not C (despite the curly brackets)
 b) global variables are pure evil 
c) that is a horribly inefficient way of achieving the result

, so any better solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 26):

Making heavy use of some R idioms:

```
> split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1)))
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 3 4 5

$`3`
[1]  9 10

$`4`
[1] 17

$`5`
[1] 29 30
```

Answer (score 13):

daroczig writes "you could write a lot neater code based on `diff`"...

Here's one way:

```
split(v, cumsum(diff(c(-Inf, v)) != 1))
```

EDIT (added timings):

Tommy discovered this could be faster by being careful with types; the reason it got faster is that `split` is faster on integers, and is actually faster still on factors.

Here's Joshua's solution; the result from the `cumsum` is a numeric because it's being `c`'d with `1`, so it's the slowest.

```
system.time({
a <- cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1))
split(v, a)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.839   0.004   1.848
```

Just `c`ing with `1L` so the result is an integer speeds it up considerably.

```
system.time({
a <- cumsum(c(1L, diff(v) != 1))
split(v, a)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.744   0.000   0.746
```

This is Tommy's solution, for reference; it's also splitting on an integer.

```
> system.time({
a <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v) != 1L))
split(v, a)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.742   0.000   0.746
```

Here's my original solution; it also is splitting on an integer.

```
system.time({
a <- cumsum(diff(c(-Inf, v)) != 1)
split(v, a)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.750   0.000   0.754
```

Here's Joshua's, with the result converted to an integer before the `split`.

```
system.time({
a <- cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1))
a <- as.integer(a)
split(v, a)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.736   0.002   0.740
```

All the versions that `split` on an integer vector are about the same; it could be even faster if that integer vector was already a factor, as the conversion from integer to factor actually takes about half the time. Here I make it into a factor directly; this is not recommended in general because it depends on the structure of the factor class.  It'ss done here for comparison purposes only.

```
system.time({
a <- cumsum(c(1L, diff(v) != 1))
a <- structure(a, class = "factor", levels = 1L:a[length(a)])
split(v,a)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.356   0.000   0.357
```

Comment: yes, this is a lot neater way! :) I did not know about `split`, thank you for pointing my attention to this useful function.

Comment: I should note that one should be careful when using `as.integer` as it returns the truncated value, which may not be what you want when the numeric was created with floating point arithmetic, for example, `as.integer(0.3*3+0.1)` returns `0`.

Comment: Can you explain what the diff() function is doing and how it works? The official documentation did not help me understand it at all.

Comment: It simply computes the differences between the terms. The help is perhaps confusing because it is more general than that, in that it allows different lags, and for the process to be repeated, for a double difference (difference of the differences) and so on.

Answer (score 8):

Joshua and Aaron were spot on. However, their code can still be made more than twice as fast by careful use of the correct types, integers and logicals:

```
split(v, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v) != 1L)))

v <- rep(c(1:5, 19), len = 1e6) # Huge vector...
system.time( split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1))) ) # Joshua's code
# user  system elapsed 
#   2.64    0.00    2.64 

system.time( split(v, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v) != 1L))) ) # Modified code
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.09    0.00    1.12
```

Comment: Wow!  I wouldn't have guessed it would make such a difference.

Comment: Tommy, I figured out why it was faster and edited your post to add it.  I'm not sure if that's the proper etiquette; hopefully you don't mind.  (Also, it has to be peer-reviewed, so if you don't see it right away, that's why.)

Comment: Apparently my edit was rejected; I've added the timings to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could define the cut-points easily:

```
which(diff(v) != 1)
```

Based on that try:

```
v <- c(1,3,4,5,9,10,17,29,30)
cutpoints <- c(0, which(diff(v) != 1), length(v))
ragged.vector <- vector("list", length(cutpoints)-1)
for (i in 2:length(cutpoints)) ragged.vector[[i-1]] <- v[(cutpoints[i-1]+1):cutpoints[i]]
```

Which results in:

```
> ragged.vector
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1]  9 10

[[4]]
[1] 17

[[5]]
[1] 29 30
```

This algorithm is not a nice one but you could write a lot neater code based on `diff` :) Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `data.frame` and assign the elements to groups using `diff`, `ifelse` and `cumsum`, then aggregate using `tapply`:

```
v.df <- data.frame(v = v)
v.df$group <- cumsum(ifelse(c(1, diff(v) - 1), 1, 0))
tapply(v.df$v, v.df$group, function(x) x)

$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 3 4 5

$`3`
[1]  9 10

$`4`
[1] 17

$`5`
[1] 29 30
```