# R moving data from list to data frame

Tags: r

I have a `list` that contains 0-3 id numbers like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2125233 <NA>    <NA>

[[2]]
[1] 2009281 2380145 2931851

[[3]]
[1] 1517163 2836702 2506119
```

How do I convert this to a `data frame` where the element number becomes the id and the contents of the element becomes a string/factor like this:

```
  id                   contents
   1             2125233 <NA>    <NA>
   2             2009281 2380145 2931851
   3             1517163 2836702 2506119
  ...                 .....
```

I've tried looking at `unlist` but it just throws everything into one long vector.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please start using `dput` as a means to show us the data object you're working with?  Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer for the most efficient methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942760/most-efficient-list-to-data-frame-method

Comment: @mnel That question is about list of _columns_ to data.frame. This one's about list of _rows_ to data.frame; i.e., `rbindlist` (when that is relaxed to accept non `data.table`, [FR#2264](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2264&group_id=240&atid=978)).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- very true. I meant to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728407/trouble-converting-long-list-of-data-frames-1-million-to-single-data-frame-us/12290824#12290824

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List <- list(c(123, NA, NA), c(1223, 4546,5656), c(4546,4646,464))
> List
[[1]]
[1] 123  NA  NA

[[2]]
[1] 1223 4546 5656

[[3]]
[1] 4546 4646  464

> data.frame(do.call(rbind, List))

    X1   X2   X3
1  123   NA   NA
2 1223 4546 5656
3 4546 4646  464
```

Answer (score 5):

The `do.call(rbind...)` approach [mentioned by Jilber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587145/1270695) is probably the most common or intuitive (and faster than the following approach), but you weren't too far off if you wanted to use `unlist`.

The trick is to use `matrix()` in conjunction with `unlist`, setting the number of rows to be the `length` of your list.

```
List <- list(c(123, NA, NA), c(1223, 4546,5656), c(4546,4646,464))
matrix(unlist(List), nrow = length(List), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  123   NA   NA
# [2,] 1223 4546 5656
# [3,] 4546 4646  464

## Or, for a data.frame
data.frame(matrix(unlist(List), nrow = length(List), byrow = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(plyr)
ldply(list_name)

> x <- c(1,2,3)
> foo <- list(x,x,x)
> foo
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

> ldply(foo)
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

R `data.frames` are actually lists, which makes this an easy task if each vector in your list is a column:

```
List <- list(c(123, NA, NA), c(1223, 4546,5656), c(4546,4646,464))
DF <- data.frame(List)
```

In the case where each element of the list is a vector, you can use `do.call` and `rbind` as show by Jilber, or transpose the above `data.frame`:

```
DF <- data.frame(t(DF))
```