# How to convert a huge list-of-vector to a matrix more efficiently?

Tags: r, list, matrix, performance

I have a list of length 130,000 where each element is a character vector of length 110. I would like to convert this list to a matrix with dimension 1,430,000*10. How can I do it more efficiently?\
My code is :

```
output=NULL
for(i in 1:length(z)) {
 output=rbind(output,
              matrix(z[[i]],ncol=10,byrow=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: If you want the dimensions to be 1430000*11 why do you set ncol to be 10?

Comment: Wait- when you say that each entry has 11 characters, you mean that it is a vector with 11 items? I originally thought that each was a string with 11 characters in it. Can you show `z[1:2]` as an example?

Comment: Thank Dason and David! That's a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: @user1787675: I still don't understand. What is an "entry"? Is it a vector? Can you show `z[1:2]`?

Comment: Hi David, I looked up an dictionary and found that I mean the components in the list. I am sorry for the confusion I caused. I am not good at English ：)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This should be equivalent to your current code, only a lot faster:

```
output <- matrix(unlist(z), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Bingo.  This should be much faster than my solution too, but I couldn't think of it fast enough.

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend setting `USE.NAMES=FALSE` in `unlist` in order to save time and memory.

Comment: It should be `use.names` (i.e. in lowercase).

Comment: Just to clarify, it should be `output <- matrix(unlist(z), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE, use.names=FALSE)` to be the most efficient.

Comment: @mikey Almost. It should be: output <- matrix(unlist(z, use.names = FALSE), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

Answer (score 16):

I *think* you want

```
output <- do.call(rbind,lapply(z,matrix,ncol=10,byrow=TRUE))
```

i.e. combining @BlueMagister's use of `do.call(rbind,...)` with an `lapply` statement to convert the individual list elements into 11*10 matrices ...

Benchmarks (showing @flodel's `unlist` solution is 5x faster than mine, and 230x faster than the original approach ...)

```
n <- 1000
z <- replicate(n,matrix(1:110,ncol=10,byrow=TRUE),simplify=FALSE)
library(rbenchmark)
origfn <- function(z) {
    output <- NULL 
    for(i in 1:length(z))
        output<- rbind(output,matrix(z[[i]],ncol=10,byrow=TRUE))
}
rbindfn <- function(z) do.call(rbind,lapply(z,matrix,ncol=10,byrow=TRUE))
unlistfn <- function(z) matrix(unlist(z), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

##          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self 
## 1   origfn(z)          100  36.467  230.804    34.834    1.540  
## 2  rbindfn(z)          100   0.713    4.513     0.708    0.012 
## 3 unlistfn(z)          100   0.158    1.000     0.144    0.008
```

If this scales appropriately (i.e. you don't run into memory problems), the full problem would take about 130*0.2 seconds = 26 seconds on a comparable machine (I did this on a 2-year-old MacBook Pro).

Comment: That's magical! It takes about 20 seconds to do this on my one-year-old toshiba machine, which saves me a lot of time. And your function to show the run time is very interesting too.

Answer (score 8):

It would help to have sample information about your output. Recursively using `rbind` on bigger and bigger things is *not recommended*. My first guess at something that would help you:

```
z <- list(1:3,4:6,7:9)
do.call(rbind,z)
```

See [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224938/can-i-rbind-be-parallelized-in-r) for more efficiency, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use,

```
output <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(z))
```

The memory usage is very similar to

```
output <- matrix(unlist(z), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

Which can be verified, with `mem_changed()` from `library(pryr)`.

Answer (score -6):

you can use as.matrix as below:

```
output <- as.matrix(z)
```