# Test if a pattern is present in a list ; If Yes replace an element in another list

Tags: r, list, find-replace

In R, I want to test if a pattern is present in a list, to replace an element located at the position in another list.

Let me take an example. My first list looks like this:

table 1:

<kbd>[,1]</kbd>     <kbd>[,2]</kbd>    
<kbd>[1,]</kbd><kbd>ABBA</kbd><kbd>BBCA</kbd>
<kbd>[2,]</kbd><kbd>ABBU</kbd><kbd>CCCH</kbd>

My second list looks like this:

<kbd>[,1]</kbd>     <kbd>[,2]</kbd>    
<kbd>[1,]</kbd><kbd>KIGS</kbd><kbd>PLOM</kbd>
<kbd>[2,]</kbd><kbd>ANAM</kbd><kbd>AKAM</kbd>

I want to test the condition, if the pattern "KI" is present in my second list then replace the element at the same place in my first list.

In this case, KI is present in my second list in "KIGS" and I would replace "ABBA" by "KI". So in position [1,1] in both lists.

Is there a way to easily do that in Rand obtain the following list:

<kbd>[,1]</kbd>     <kbd>[,2]</kbd>    
<kbd>[1,]</kbd><kbd>KI</kbd>      <kbd>BBCA</kbd>
<kbd>[2,]</kbd><kbd>ABBU</kbd><kbd>CCCH</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Images of data are not very reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, but seems that HTML tables are not allowed so i edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your answer, a possible solution is using the command `ifelse` in relation with `grepl`. But, Do you have two matrix or two list? 
A list is a generic vector containing other objects, it's different from your example (read this site http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/vector-array-list-and-data-frame-in-r/).
Then:

The two matrix as examples:

```
   table1<-matrix(c("ABBA","BBCA","ABBU","CCCH"),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
   table2<-matrix(c("KIGS","BBCA","ABBU","CCCH"),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

table1
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "ABBA" "BBCA"
[2,] "ABBU" "CCCH"

table2
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "KIGS" "BBCA"
[2,] "ABBU" "CCCH"
```

I used a `for` loop with `ifelse`, conditional element selection, and `grepl` command as:

```
for(j in 1:ncol(table2)){
for(i in 1:nrow(table2)) { 
table2[i,j]<-ifelse(grepl("KI",table2[i,j])==TRUE,table1[i,j],table2[i,j])
}}
```

then we have table2 as:

```
table2
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "ABBA" "BBCA"
[2,] "ABBU" "CCCH"
```

Comment: I note now the changes of question, then instead of having `table2[i,j]<-ifelse(grepl("KI",table2[i,j])==TRUE,table1[i,j],table2[i,j])`, you can put `table1[i,j]<-ifelse(grepl("KI",table2[i,j])==TRUE,"KI",table1[i,j])`

Comment: Thanks Angella. I checked and the 2 sets of data i want to "match" are Large Lists made of 1194 elements each. 
Each element is a chr [1:2, 1:2]

Comment: Try to do this `output <- matrix(unlist(table), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)` thanks to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224553/how-to-convert-a-list-to-a-matrix-more-efficiently-in-r)

Comment: The option `ncol`  should be altered considering your specific case.