# simplifying an arbitrarily long list of data frames into a single data frame

Tags: r

I have a directory of identically structured csv files.  I'm trying to load all of them into a single data.frame.  Currently I use `lapply()` with `read.csv()` to get a list of data.frames and I am looking for an elegant way to convert this list to a data.frame that avoids an explicit loop.

The result of my `lapply(list.of.file.names,read.csv)` can be approximated as this structure:

```
list.of.dfs <- list(data.frame(A=sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10), size = 5),
                               B=sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10), size = 5)), 
                    data.frame(A=sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10), size = 5),
                               B=sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10), size = 5)), 
                    data.frame(A=sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10), size = 5),
                               B=sample(seq(from = 1, to = 10), size = 5))
                    )
```

What is an elegant version of the following line that works for arbitrary length lists:

```
one.data.frame <- rbind(list.of.dfs[[1]],list.of.dfs[[2]],list.of.dfs[[3]])
```

I can do this with a for loop, but is there a vector-based solution?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, list.of.dfs)`

Comment: Yep, this one's surprisingly easy once you know what `do.call` does.

Comment: Yup, this is a duplicate.  Somehow I didn't find the earlier one. Sheepishly voting to close my own question.

Answer (score 5):

`do.call` is the basic way of doing this.

```
do.call(rbind, list.of.dfs)
```

But it can be slow if you have a lot of data items, and other discussions here on S.O. have centred on how to speed things up by using custom functions or the `data.table` or `plyr` packages. E.g.:

[Why is rbindlist "better" than rbind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind/15673654#15673654)

[Can rbind be parallelized in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224938/can-rbind-be-parallelized-in-r)

[Performance of rbind.data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980240/performance-of-rbind-data-frame)

Answer (score 4):

@thelatemail alluded to it, but you might want to use the following for speed:

```
rbindlist(list.of.dfs)
```

*(requires `library(data.table)` )*