# Create a group number for each consecutive sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have the data.frame below. I want to add a column 'g' that classifies my data according to consecutive sequences in column `h_no`. That is, the first sequence of h_no `1, 2, 3, 4` is group 1, the second series of `h_no` (1 to 7) is group 2, and so on, as indicated in the last column 'g'.

```
h_no   h_freq    h_freqsq g
1     0.09091 0.008264628 1
2     0.00000 0.000000000 1
3     0.04545 0.002065702 1
4     0.00000 0.000000000 1  
1     0.13636 0.018594050 2
2     0.00000 0.000000000 2
3     0.00000 0.000000000 2
4     0.04545 0.002065702 2
5     0.31818 0.101238512 2
6     0.00000 0.000000000 2
7     0.50000 0.250000000 2 
1     0.13636 0.018594050 3 
2     0.09091 0.008264628 3
3     0.40909 0.167354628 3
4     0.04545 0.002065702 3
```

Comment: See also [Create grouping variable for consecutive sequences and split vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/create-grouping-variable-for-consecutive-sequences-and-split-vector)

Answer (score 158):

You can add a column to your data using various techniques. The quotes below come from the "Details" section of the relevant help text, `[[.data.frame`.

> Data frames can be indexed in several modes. When `[` and `[[` are used with a single vector index (`x[i]` or `x[[i]]`), they index the data frame as if it were a list.

```
my.dataframe["new.col"] <- a.vector
my.dataframe[["new.col"]] <- a.vector
```

> The data.frame method for `$`, treats `x` as a list

```
my.dataframe$new.col <- a.vector
```

> When `[` and `[[` are used with two indices (`x[i, j]` and `x[[i, j]]`) they act like indexing a matrix

```
my.dataframe[ , "new.col"] <- a.vector
```

Since the method for `data.frame` assumes that if you don't specify if you're working with columns or rows, it will assume you mean columns.

---

For your example, this should work:

```
# make some fake data
your.df <- data.frame(no = c(1:4, 1:7, 1:5), h_freq = runif(16), h_freqsq = runif(16))

# find where one appears and 
from <- which(your.df$no == 1)
to <- c((from-1)[-1], nrow(your.df)) # up to which point the sequence runs

# generate a sequence (len) and based on its length, repeat a consecutive number len times
get.seq <- mapply(from, to, 1:length(from), FUN = function(x, y, z) {
            len <- length(seq(from = x[1], to = y[1]))
            return(rep(z, times = len))
         })

# when we unlist, we get a vector
your.df$group <- unlist(get.seq)
# and append it to your original data.frame. since this is
# designating a group, it makes sense to make it a factor
your.df$group <- as.factor(your.df$group)


   no     h_freq   h_freqsq group
1   1 0.40998238 0.06463876     1
2   2 0.98086928 0.33093795     1
3   3 0.28908651 0.74077119     1
4   4 0.10476768 0.56784786     1
5   1 0.75478995 0.60479945     2
6   2 0.26974011 0.95231761     2
7   3 0.53676266 0.74370154     2
8   4 0.99784066 0.37499294     2
9   5 0.89771767 0.83467805     2
10  6 0.05363139 0.32066178     2
11  7 0.71741529 0.84572717     2
12  1 0.10654430 0.32917711     3
13  2 0.41971959 0.87155514     3
14  3 0.32432646 0.65789294     3
15  4 0.77896780 0.27599187     3
16  5 0.06100008 0.55399326     3
```

Comment: What's the difference between the last two methods of adding a column?

Comment: @huon-dbaupp the method with a comma is explicit and will also work on matrices, while the last one works on data.frames only. If no comma is provided, R assumes you mean columns.

Answer (score 13):

Easily: Your data frame is A

```
b <- A[,1]
b <- b==1
b <- cumsum(b)
```

Then you get the column b.

Comment: Nice and short. I would just change the last element so that instead of being `cumsum(b) -> b` the result would be directly added as a column to the original data frame, something like `A$groups <- cumsum(b)`.

Comment: `cumsum(b)` will give you a vector of length 3, or am I missing something?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, see [dbaupp's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10152086/1270695) which explains how cumsum would work in this case.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, This solution can be rewritten really nicely in a single line. Using your `your.df` data, you can simply do `your.df$group = cumsum(your.df[, 1]==1)` to get your new group column.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to detect when the `h_no` doesn't increase and then increment the `class`. (I'm going to walk through how I solved this problem, there is a self-contained function at the end.)

### Working

We only care about the `h_no` column for the moment, so we can extract that from the data frame:

```
> h_no <- data$h_no
```

We want to detect when `h_no` doesn't go up, which we can do by working out when the difference between successive elements is either negative or zero. R provides the [`diff`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html) function which gives us the vector of differences:

```
> d.h_no <- diff(h_no)
> d.h_no
 [1]  1  1  1 -3  1  1  1  1  1  1 -6  1  1  1
```

Once we have that, it is a simple matter to find the ones that are non-positive:

```
> nonpos <- d.h_no <= 0
> nonpos
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE
```

In R, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are basically the same as `1` and `0`, so if we get the cumulative sum of `nonpos`, it will increase by 1 in (almost) the appropriate spots. The [`cumsum`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html) function (which is basically the opposite of `diff`) can do this.

```
> cumsum(nonpos)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

But, there are two problems: the numbers are one too small; and, we are missing the first element (there should be four in the first class).

The first problem is simply solved: `1+cumsum(nonpos)`. And the second just requires adding a `1` to the front of the vector, since the first element is always in class `1`:

```
 > classes <- c(1, 1 + cumsum(nonpos))
 > classes
  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Now, we can attach it back onto our data frame with [`cbind`](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/base/html/cbind.html) (by using the `class=` syntax, we can give the column the `class` heading):

```
 > data_w_classes <- cbind(data, class=classes)
```

And `data_w_classes` now contains the result.

### Final result

We can compress the lines together and wrap it all up into a function to make it easier to use:

```
classify <- function(data) {
   cbind(data, class=c(1, 1 + cumsum(diff(data$h_no) <= 0)))
}
```

Or, since it makes sense for the `class` to be a factor:

```
classify <- function(data) {
   cbind(data, class=factor(c(1, 1 + cumsum(diff(data$h_no) <= 0))))
}
```

You use either function like:

```
> classified <- classify(data) # doesn't overwrite data
> data <- classify(data) # data now has the "class" column
```

(This method of solving this problem is good because it avoids explicit iteration, which is generally recommend for R, and avoids generating lots of intermediate vectors and list etc. And also it's kinda neat how it can be written on one line :) )

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Roman's answer, something like this might be even simpler. Note that I haven't tested it because I do not have access to R right now.

```
# Note that I use a global variable here
# normally not advisable, but I liked the
# use here to make the code shorter
index <<- 0
new_column = sapply(df$h_no, function(x) {
  if(x == 1) index = index + 1
  return(index)
})
```

The function iterates over the values in `n_ho` and always returns the categorie that the current value belongs to. If a value of `1` is detected, we increase the global variable `index` and continue.

Comment: I like the hack with the global variable. So Cish. :P

Answer (score 1):

A good option is `collapse::seqid`, which creates unique IDs from sequences of consecutive numbers. The function is highly optimized and flexible:

```r
collapse::seqid(df$h_no)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

---

```r
collapse::seqid(c(1:5, 7:10))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

collapse::seqid(c(1:5, 7:10), del = 2) #With a delimitation of 2
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8

collapse::seqid(c(1, NA, 2), na.skip = TRUE)
#[1]  1 NA  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using "cbind" is the simplest way to add a column to a data frame in R. Below an example:

```
    myDf = data.frame(index=seq(1,10,1), Val=seq(1,10,1))
    newCol= seq(2,20,2)
    myDf = cbind(myDf,newCol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach based on identifying number of groups (`x` in `mapply`) and its length (`y` in `mapply`)

```
mytb<-read.table(text="h_no  h_freq  h_freqsq group
1     0.09091 0.008264628 1
2     0.00000 0.000000000 1
3     0.04545 0.002065702 1
4     0.00000 0.000000000 1  
1     0.13636 0.018594050 2
2     0.00000 0.000000000 2
3     0.00000 0.000000000 2
4     0.04545 0.002065702 2
5     0.31818 0.101238512 2
6     0.00000 0.000000000 2
7     0.50000 0.250000000 2 
1     0.13636 0.018594050 3 
2     0.09091 0.008264628 3
3     0.40909 0.167354628 3
4     0.04545 0.002065702 3", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
mytb$group<-NULL

positionsof1s<-grep(1,mytb$h_no)

mytb$newgroup<-unlist(mapply(function(x,y) 
  rep(x,y),                      # repeat x number y times
  x= 1:length(positionsof1s),    # x is 1 to number of nth group = g1:g3
  y= c( diff(positionsof1s),     # y is number of repeats of groups g1 to penultimate (g2) = 4, 7
        nrow(mytb)-              # this line and the following gives number of repeat for last group (g3)
          (positionsof1s[length(positionsof1s )]-1 )  # number of rows - position of penultimate group (g2) 
      ) ) )
mytb
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` function `rleid` is handy for things like this. We subtract the sequence `1:nrow(data)` to transform consecutive sequences to constants, and then use `rleid` to create the group IDs:

```
data$g = data.table::rleid(data$h_no - 1:nrow(data))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Data.frame[,'h_new_column'] <- as.integer(Data.frame[,'h_no'], breaks=c(1, 4, 7))
```