# R: Error: vector are not the same length in a for loop

Tags: r

I am starting to learn R and I got an error for the loop.

Here is the error I got:

```
Error in names(data1)[5] <- "TR" : 
'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [4]
```

Here is my code:

```
#read data
data1<-read.table("C_0.txt",header = T,sep=",")

#name the 5th col TR
names(data1)[5]<-"TR"

#calculate the length of data1
n<-nrow(data1)

#initialize first TR value to NA
data1[1,5]<-NA

for (i in 1:(n-1)){

if (data1[i,3]==data1[i+1,3]) {data1[i+1,5]<-data1[i,5]}

if (data1[i,3]< data1[i+1,3]) {data1[i+1,5]<- 1}

if(data1[i,3]> data1[i+1,3]) {data1[i+1,5]<- -1}
}
```

Here is the algorithm I am trying to codify:
if the current price is above the previous price, mark +1 in the column named TR
if the current price is below the previous price, mark -1 in the column named TR
if the current price is the same as the previous price, mark the same thing as in the previous price in the column named TR

I marked the first TR row as NA because there is no price to compare it to.

here is the data from C_0.txt:

```
Date,Time,Price,Size
02/18/2014,05:06:13,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:13,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:13,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:14,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:14,49.6,193
02/18/2014,05:44:41,49.62,100
02/18/2014,06:26:36,49.52,100
02/18/2014,06:26:36,49.52,500
02/18/2014,07:09:29,49.6,100
02/18/2014,07:56:40,49.56,300
02/18/2014,07:56:40,49.55,400
02/18/2014,07:56:41,49.54,200
02/18/2014,07:56:43,49.55,100
02/18/2014,07:56:43,49.55,100
02/18/2014,07:56:50,49.55,100
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.53,100
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.51,2200
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.51,100
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.5,200
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error is not from your loop, but when you attempt to name a non-existent column. There is no such thing as `names(dat1)[5]`, so it can't be assigned `"TR"`.

Comment: How would I add a fifth column?

Comment: here is what I did, but the it takes too long - the file is 6MB.    data1["TR"]<-NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a column to a data frame is fairly basic stuff. Here's a question that summarises that.

You can't add a column to a data frame by changing the length of the names attribute vector. You have to create it by methods like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150579/adding-a-column-to-a-data-frame).

As for the other part of your question, let's use `diff` and `rle` instead of a for-loop.

```
d <-  read.table(sep = ",", text = 
"Date,Time,Price,Size
02/18/2014,05:06:13,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:13,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:13,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:14,49.6,200
02/18/2014,05:06:14,49.6,193
02/18/2014,05:44:41,49.62,100
02/18/2014,06:26:36,49.52,100
02/18/2014,06:26:36,49.52,500
02/18/2014,07:09:29,49.6,100
02/18/2014,07:56:40,49.56,300
02/18/2014,07:56:40,49.55,400
02/18/2014,07:56:41,49.54,200
02/18/2014,07:56:43,49.55,100
02/18/2014,07:56:43,49.55,100
02/18/2014,07:56:50,49.55,100
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.53,100
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.51,2200
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.51,100
02/18/2014,07:57:12,49.5,200", header = TRUE)

tmp <- c(NA, diff(d$Price))
tmp <- sign(tmp)
tmp <- rle(tmp)
l <- tmp$lengths
v <- tmp$values
idx <- which(v == 0L)
l[idx - 1] <- l[idx - 1] + l[idx]
l <- l[-idx]
v <- v[-idx]
d$TR <- inverse.rle(list(lengths = l, values = v))

#          Date     Time Price Size TR
# 1  02/18/2014 05:06:13 49.60  200 NA
# 2  02/18/2014 05:06:13 49.60  200 NA
# 3  02/18/2014 05:06:13 49.60  200 NA
# 4  02/18/2014 05:06:14 49.60  200 NA
# 5  02/18/2014 05:06:14 49.60  193 NA
# 6  02/18/2014 05:44:41 49.62  100  1
# 7  02/18/2014 06:26:36 49.52  100 -1
# 8  02/18/2014 06:26:36 49.52  500 -1
# 9  02/18/2014 07:09:29 49.60  100  1
# 10 02/18/2014 07:56:40 49.56  300 -1
# 11 02/18/2014 07:56:40 49.55  400 -1
# 12 02/18/2014 07:56:41 49.54  200 -1
# 13 02/18/2014 07:56:43 49.55  100  1
# 14 02/18/2014 07:56:43 49.55  100  1
# 15 02/18/2014 07:56:50 49.55  100  1
# 16 02/18/2014 07:57:12 49.53  100 -1
# 17 02/18/2014 07:57:12 49.51 2200 -1
# 18 02/18/2014 07:57:12 49.51  100 -1
# 19 02/18/2014 07:57:12 49.50  200 -1
```

Comment: Hi Blue Magister, what does `l[idx - 1] <- l[idx - 1] + l[idx]` do? and what does it mean to negate an index like `l <- l[-idx]`?

Comment: `idx` finds where there are zeroes in the run-length encoding. The first line you question adds the run of zeroes to the previous run. Then `l[-idx]` and `v[-idx]` delete the zeroes. It will help to step through the code, seeing how `l` and `v` change.

Comment: Thank you Blue Magister for your help