# R: add new column to a list of data frames with lapply

Tags: r

i've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150579/adding-a-column-to-a-data-frame/) and have created a lapply function to add a "SubCat" column to every data frame within a list.

This is my code:

```
    my_list <- lapply(1:length(my_list),     
               function(i) cbind(my_list[[i]], my_list[[i]]["SubCat"] <- as.character("")))
```

But get this error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "SubCat", value = "") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Whats wrong?

When i use it, on a single data frame it works:

```
my_list[[1]]["SubCat"] <- as.character("")
```

UPDATE:

These are examples of my data frames, they all contain the same structure. One column for SKU and one for the Category.

DataFrame 1:

```
    row.names       SKU         Tv.y.Video
1   1699        2018143169254P  Tv.y.Video
2   1700        2018143169254   Tv.y.Video
3   1946        2018144678120P  Tv.y.Video
4   1947        2018144678120   Tv.y.Video
5   2366        2018146411831P  Tv.y.Video
6   2367        2018146411831   Tv.y.Video
```

DataFrame 2:

```
    row.names   SKU             C�mputo
1     6       2004121460000P    C�mputo
2     7       2004121460000     C�mputo
3     8       2004121440002P    C�mputo
4     9       2004121440002     C�mputo
5     10      2004123030003P    C�mputo
6     11      2004123030003     C�mputo
```

When i applied my code to just one df it works:

```
my_list[[1]]["SubCat"] <- as.character("")
```

Result:

```
    row.names       SKU         Tv.y.Video    SubCat
1   1699        2018143169254P  Tv.y.Video   
2   1700        2018143169254   Tv.y.Video   
3   1946        2018144678120P  Tv.y.Video   
4   1947        2018144678120   Tv.y.Video   
5   2366        2018146411831P  Tv.y.Video   
6   2367        2018146411831   Tv.y.Video
```

***UPDATE 1:***

I also have some empty data.frames in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `my_list[[1]]["SubCat"] <- as.character("")` doesn't return anything, so, after the expression is evaluated you have `NULL` as data and the `cbind` process cannot execute it accordingly. Also, `lapply` will execute your function for each and every `data frame` in your list, so your command should like as follows:

```
vec.1 <- c(1, 2)
vec.2 <- c(2, 3)
df.1 <- data.frame(vec.1, vec.2)
df.2 <- data.frame(vec.2, vec.1)
my_list <- list(df.1, df.2)
## This is the correct use of lapply for your list
my_list <- lapply(my_list, cbind, SubCat = c(""))
my_list
[[1]]
  vec.1 vec.2 SubCat
1     1     2       
2     2     3       

[[2]]
  vec.2 vec.1 SubCat
1     2     1       
2     3     2
```

**EDIT:** 
`lapply` takes a list as argument and a function to apply in each and every one of the list's elements. However, `cbind` requires two arguments. The additional arguments are passed with `lapply`. Now, you may notice that the `SubCat` vector consists of one null string; that is OK, because R repeats that vector as many times as needed.

**EDIT #2:**
Hmm, this error is probably coming from the empty data.frames, which I didn't take into account. You could do this to solve your problem (I didn't take into account that a vector *cannot repeat itself zero times*):

```
my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(df){
    if (nrow(df) > 0)
        cbind(df, SubCat = c(""))
    else
        cbind(df, SubCat = character())
    })
```

**Added by the author of the question:**

> It is OK, to complete a column with blanks("") according to the
>   other columns `SubCat = c("")`. But, if you have an empty data frame,
>   you need to start a new column with: `SubCat = character()`, which is a zero length column.

Comment: I got a different error: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`

Comment: That's weird. Could you edit your first post and add an example so that I can reproduce it?

Comment: i did that, check and tell me if that works for you.

Comment: Do you by any chance have any empty data frames in you list?

Comment: Yes, i have more than 10 i think. I think i should have mentioned that.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the cause of the error. The last piece of code should do the job for you, by first checking whether the current data frame is empty or not. Please feel free to comment, should you have any questions.

Comment: thanks this did the job. I've edited you answer to make it a bit clear as i understund it. Please, check it and make any modifications you would like.

Comment: @nikaltipar, what if the `Subcat` here is element dependent, say the name of the element in the list.

Comment: You might want to ask a different question to address this. SubCat uses a constant value. It's also been a few years since I touched R and I don't feel I could provide you with a very good solution.