# Compare two columns for string and print "TRUE" or "FALSE"

Tags: r, compare

I have a df with two columns containing strings with false negative and false positive calls. I'd like to compare the two columns and identify the ones that are both "FN" and "FP" and make a third column with a "tag" indicating whether the columns meet the specs of the query.

For example here's a piece of the df

```
x1           x2
1/2:FN:am    .:.:.
1|1:FN:am    0/1:FP:am
.:.:.        1|0:559.511:FP
```

I'd like the resulting output to be

```
x1           x2               x3
1/2:FN:am    .:.:.            False
1|1:FN:am    0/1:FP:am        True
.:.:.        1|0:559.511:FP   False
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer you are searching for is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10152029/7019856

Comment: @gima I'm not seeing how this applies. There is no comparison between columns going in in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Does this give you what you need?

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c("1:FN:AM","1.2:FN:AM","3"),x2=c("1:AM","1.2:FP:AM","3"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
         x1        x2
1   1:FN:AM      1:AM
2 1.2:FN:AM 1.2:FP:AM
3         3         3

df$x3 <- sapply(df$x1,grepl,pattern = "FN") & sapply(df$x2,grepl,pattern = "FP")
         x1        x2    x3
1   1:FN:AM      1:AM FALSE
2 1.2:FN:AM 1.2:FP:AM  TRUE
3         3         3 FALSE
```

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure why people didn't care for the question but your answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This also works (this captures any of the patterns (FP in x1 and FN in x2) or (FN in x1 and FP in x2))

```
df <- read.table(text='x1           x2
                 1/2:FN:am    .:.:.
                 1|1:FN:am    0/1:FP:am
                 1|0:55:FP    0/2:FN:am
                 .:.:.        1|0:559.511:FP', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$x3 <- grepl('.*FN.*FP.*|.*FP.*FN.*', paste(df$x1, df$x2))
df
#         x1             x2    x3
#1 1/2:FN:am          .:.:. FALSE
#2 1|1:FN:am      0/1:FP:am  TRUE
#3 1|0:55:FP      0/2:FN:am  TRUE
#4     .:.:. 1|0:559.511:FP FALSE
```