# R: Why adding a new column to a data frame generates two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a column to a data frame that has a fix value, so based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150579/adding-a-column-to-a-data-frame) I do :

```
lessthan7.labels [, 'interval']=  c(rep( 'week', nrow(lessthan7)))
```

but then it creates two columns:  "interval", "rep(\"week\", nrow(lessthan7))".

How to get rid of this extra column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to assign a constant value to a new column in a data frame, you can just use the following list notation:

```
lessthan7$interval <- 'week'
```