# How to use lubridate to mutate my character columns to dates?

Tags: r, date, datetime, parsing, lubridate

I've imported a dataset with dates in the format 'month year' (e.g. `July 2020`), which have automatically been parsed as characters. I'm trying to convert them to dates, using `lubridate::parse_date_time()`. When I do this, lubridate returns a list of dates (e.g. `"2020-07-01 UTC", "2020-07-01 UTC", "2020-07-01 UTC", "2020-07-01 UTC", "2020-07-01 UTC", "2020-06-01 UTC", "2020-06-01 UTC", "2020-06-01 UTC", "2020-06-01 UTC", "2020-06-01 UTC"` etc).

This is what I want, but now I'm stuck: I'm not sure how to get these back into my original dataframe, replacing the previous column of characters with this new date representation. Is there a really obvious way to do this?

Comment: Hi bee, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(data)` or if your data is very large `dput(data[1:20,])`. You should replace `data` with the name of your actual data.frame. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a column to a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150579/adding-a-column-to-a-data-frame)

Comment: @IanCampbell Along with the below answer this cleared up the problem! I will make sure to provide a sample of my data next time I ask a question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`dataframe %>% mutate(date = parse_date_time(date)) -> dataframe`

or

`dataframe$date <- parse_date_time(dataframe$date)`