# Loading txt file into R and replace some value based on other data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, readlines

I have a large txt file containing specific format structure. My goal is to load text in R using `readLines` and I want to replace weight value of each record with new value based on my df data frame. I don't want to change the .txt data structure format or parse the .txt file. Final output should have the exact same structure as the original .txt (`writeLines()`). How can I read it and update the value? Thanks

Here is my reference data frame

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~House_id,  ~id, ~new_weight,
  18105265, "Mab",        4567,
  18117631, "Maa",        3367,
  18121405, "Mab",        4500,
  71811763, "Maa",        2455,
  71811763, "Mab",        2872
  )
```

Here is a small subset of my .txt

```
H18105265_0
R1_0
Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959
H18117631_0
R1_0
Maa_1240111711220682016_W123650.80
T1_0
V74_0_1_010_aa081200081259_aa081600081859_aa082100095659_aa095700101159_aa101300105059
H18121405_0
R1_0
Mab_2467211713110643835_W923650.80
T1_0
T2_0
V62_0_1_010_090500092459_100500101059_101100101659_140700140859_141100141359
H71811763_0
R1_0
Maa_5325411210120486554_W923650.80
Mab_5325411210110485554_W723650.80
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
T4_0
```

Here the the desire output for first individual record house_id = 18105265: Update `Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80`
line with new value `Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567` base of **df**

```
H18105265_0
R1_0
Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959
```

Comment: How do you know that  `Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567` is not `Mab_3416311514210525745_W4500`?

Comment: H refers to house_Id and id refers to individual id. I updated the question

Comment: what do you mean by "I dont want to [...] parse the .txt file"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT - added `id` to lookup to distinguish between non-unique House_id.

Here's an approach where I read the data, join to the updated weights in `df`, and then create an updated value on the rows that start with "M" using that new weight.

```
library(tidyverse)
read_fwf("txt_sample.txt" ,  col_positions = fwf_empty("txt_sample.txt")) %>% # edit suggested by DanG

# if the row starts with H, extract 8 digit house number and
# use that to join to the table with new weights
mutate(House_id = if_else(str_starts(X1, "H"), as.numeric(str_sub(X1, 2,9)), NA_real_),
       id = if_else(str_starts(X1, "M"), str_sub(X1, 1,3), NA_character_)) %>%
fill(House_id) %>%
left_join(df, by = c("House_id", "id")) %>%
fill(new_weight) %>%

# make new string using updated weight (or keep existing string)
mutate(X1_new = coalesce(
  if_else(str_starts(X1, "M"),
          paste0(word(X1, end = 2, sep = "_"), "_W", new_weight),
          NA_character_),
  X1)) %>%

pull(X1_new) %>% 
writeLines()
```

Output

```
H18105265_0
R1_0
Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959
H18117631_0
R1_0
Maa_1240111711220682016_W3367
T1_0
V74_0_1_010_aa081200081259_aa081600081859_aa082100095659_aa095700101159_aa101300105059
H18121405_0
R1_0
Mab_2467211713110643835_W4500
T1_0
T2_0
V62_0_1_010_090500092459_100500101059_101100101659_140700140859_141100141359
H71811763_0
R1_0
Maa_5325411210120486554_W2455
Mab_5325411210110485554_W2872
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
T4_0
```

Comment: I guess the last `Maa` and `Mab` should have different new weights, rather than 2827 for both.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I hadn't realized multiple ids per house possible.

Comment: Nice solution and upvoted already for it.

Comment: Very nice solution. @JonSpring Thanks . I added this to be able to read the file `read_fwf("txt_sample.txt" ,  col_positions = fwf_empty("txt_sample.txt")) `

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following base R code

```
writeLines(
  do.call(
    paste0,
    lapply(
      unlist(
        strsplit(
          readChar("test.txt", file.info("test.txt")$size),
          "(?<=\\d)\n(?=H)",
          perl = TRUE
        )
      ),
      function(x) {
        with(
          df,
          Reduce(
            function(x, ps) sub(ps[[1]], ps[[2]], x),
            asplit(rbind(
              unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("W.*(?=\n)", x, perl = TRUE))),
              paste0("W", new_weight[sapply(sprintf("H%s.*%s_\\d+_W", House_id, id), grepl, x)])
            ), 2),
            init = x
          )
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
H18105265_0
R1_0
Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959
H18117631_0
R1_0
Maa_1240111711220682016_W3367
T1_0
V74_0_1_010_aa081200081259_aa081600081859_aa082100095659_aa095700101159_aa101300105059
H18121405_0
R1_0
Mab_2467211713110643835_W4500
T1_0
T2_0
V62_0_1_010_090500092459_100500101059_101100101659_140700140859_141100141359
H71811763_0
R1_0
Maa_5325411210120486554_W2455
Mab_5325411210110485554_W2872
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
T4_0
```

## break down codes

- We first use the following code to divide the long string into smaller blocks

```
      unlist(
        strsplit(
          readChar("test.txt", file.info("test.txt")$size),
          "(?<=\\d)\n(?=H)",
          perl = TRUE
        )
      )
```

- For the sub-string in each block, we find the matched `House_id` + `id`, and replace the weight part, e.g., `Wxxxxxx` with corresponding `new_weight` value

```
        with(
          df,
          Reduce(
            function(x, ps) sub(ps[[1]], ps[[2]], x),
            asplit(
              rbind(
              unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("W.*(?=\n)", x, perl = TRUE))),
              paste0("W", new_weight[sapply(sprintf("H%s.*%s_\\d+_W", House_id, id), grepl, x)])
            ), 2),
            init = x
          )
        )
```

Note that the last block has two different matched `id`, we use `Reduce` to replace the weights iteratively

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over the various lines you obtain after a `readlines` of your text document. You can parse the `House_id` from the lines starting with `H` using `hpatt = 'H[0-9]+_0'` as regular expression, and then apply the `stringr` package to process lines:

```
for (i in 1:length(lines)){
  line = lines[[i]]

  #detect if line looks like 'H[number]_0'
  if (stringr::str_detect(line, hpatt)){
    #if it does, extract the 'house_id' from the line
    h_id = stringr::str_extract(test, pattern = 'H[0-9]+') %>% 
      stringr::str_replace('H|_0','')
  }
```

In the second part, you can replace the original weight with one obtained from your tibble (which I've dubbed `replacetibble` here). I'm using the regex `mpatt = '^[a-zA-z]+_[0-9]+_W[0-9\\.]+$'`, which looks for strings that look like `[character-onlyname]_[number]_W[numberwithdecimal]`:

```
  if (stringr::str_detect(line, mpatt)){
    # split string to get 'id'
    id = stringr::str_split(line, '_')[[1]][[1]]
    # look up weight
    wt = (replacetibble %>% filter(house_id==h_id & id == id) %>% select(weight))
    # replace number in line, split the original line by the 'W'
    # this will of course break if your id contains a W - please
    # adapt logic according to your naming rules
    replaceline = stringr::str_split(line, 'W')[[1]]
    replaceline[length(replaceline)] =wt
    # put the line back together with a 'W' character
    lines[[i]] = paste0(replaceline, collapse = 'W')
  }
}
```

`Stringr` (cheat sheet [here](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/strings.pdf)) is generally quite powerful in manipulating strings.

I'll leave the loading and saving part up to you.

Comment: it should be [H]_[id]_w[weight]. H refers to house_Id and id refers to individual id. I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put each step in a new object to better understand what is going on. In case any regex is unclear to you, do not hesitate to ask.

Ids are not limited to any number of digits, Individual Ids are just limited to start with "Ma(any character)_" and could easily be expanded, and hence one house ID could contain any number of individuals.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~House_id,  ~id, ~new_weight,
  18105265, "Mab",        4567,
  18117631, "Maa",        3367,
  18121405, "Mab",        4500,
  71811763, "Maa",        2455,
  71811763, "Mab",        2872
)

# read the data
dat <- readLines("test.txt")

# convert to tibble
dat2 <- tibble::tibble(X = dat)

# keep relevant info, i.e. house IDs and individual IDs
dat3 <- dat2 %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  filter(grepl(pattern = "H[0-9]+_0", X) | 
           grepl(pattern = "^Ma._[0-9]+", X))
dat3
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>   rowid X                                 
#>   <int> <chr>                             
#> 1     1 H18105265_0                       
#> 2     3 Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80
#> 3     8 H18117631_0                       
#> 4    10 Maa_1240111711220682016_W123650.80
#> 5    13 H18121405_0                       
#> 6    15 Mab_2467211713110643835_W923650.80
#> 7    19 H71811763_0                       
#> 8    21 Maa_5325411210120486554_W923650.80
#> 9    22 Mab_5325411210110485554_W723650.80


# determine which individuals belong to which house
dat4 <- dat3 %>% 
  mutate(house1 = grepl(pattern = "H[0-9]+_0", X)) %>% 
  mutate(house2 = cumsum(house1))
dat4
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   rowid X                                  house1 house2
#>   <int> <chr>                              <lgl>   <int>
#> 1     1 H18105265_0                        TRUE        1
#> 2     3 Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80 FALSE       1
#> 3     8 H18117631_0                        TRUE        2
#> 4    10 Maa_1240111711220682016_W123650.80 FALSE       2
#> 5    13 H18121405_0                        TRUE        3
#> 6    15 Mab_2467211713110643835_W923650.80 FALSE       3
#> 7    19 H71811763_0                        TRUE        4
#> 8    21 Maa_5325411210120486554_W923650.80 FALSE       4
#> 9    22 Mab_5325411210110485554_W723650.80 FALSE       4


dat4b <- dat4 %>% 
  filter(grepl(pattern = "H[0-9]+_0", X)) %>% 
  select(house_id = X, house2)
dat4b
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   house_id    house2
#>   <chr>        <int>
#> 1 H18105265_0      1
#> 2 H18117631_0      2
#> 3 H18121405_0      3
#> 4 H71811763_0      4


# combine house and individual ids next to each other
dat5 <- dat4 %>% 
  left_join(dat4b,
            by = "house2") %>% 
  mutate(prefix = gsub(pattern = "_.+", replacement = "", x = X),
         house_id = as.numeric(gsub("^H|_0", "", house_id))) %>% 
  select(rowid, house_id, prefix, X) %>% 
  filter(grepl(pattern = "^Ma._[0-9]+", X)) 
dat5
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   rowid house_id prefix X                                 
#>   <int>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                             
#> 1     3 18105265 Mab    Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80
#> 2    10 18117631 Maa    Maa_1240111711220682016_W123650.80
#> 3    15 18121405 Mab    Mab_2467211713110643835_W923650.80
#> 4    21 71811763 Maa    Maa_5325411210120486554_W923650.80
#> 5    22 71811763 Mab    Mab_5325411210110485554_W723650.80


# add he new information about individual ids
dat6 <- left_join(dat5, df,
                  by = c("house_id" = "House_id",
                         "prefix" = "id"))
dat6
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   rowid house_id prefix X                                  new_weight
#>   <int>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                                   <dbl>
#> 1     3 18105265 Mab    Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80       4567
#> 2    10 18117631 Maa    Maa_1240111711220682016_W123650.80       3367
#> 3    15 18121405 Mab    Mab_2467211713110643835_W923650.80       4500
#> 4    21 71811763 Maa    Maa_5325411210120486554_W923650.80       2455
#> 5    22 71811763 Mab    Mab_5325411210110485554_W723650.80       2872


# generate the new ids
dat7 <- dat6 %>% 
  mutate(Y = gsub(pattern = "(?=W).+", replacement = "", x = X, perl = T),
         X_new = paste0(Y, "W", new_weight)) %>% 
  select(rowid, X_new)
dat7
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   rowid X_new                        
#>   <int> <chr>                        
#> 1     3 Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567
#> 2    10 Maa_1240111711220682016_W3367
#> 3    15 Mab_2467211713110643835_W4500
#> 4    21 Maa_5325411210120486554_W2455
#> 5    22 Mab_5325411210110485554_W2872


# replace the old ids by the new ones
dat[dat7$rowid] <- dat7$X_new
dat
#>  [1] "H18105265_0"                                                                           
#>  [2] "R1_0"                                                                                  
#>  [3] "Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567"                                                         
#>  [4] "T1_0"                                                                                  
#>  [5] "T2_0"                                                                                  
#>  [6] "T3_0"                                                                                  
#>  [7] "V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959"                                                            
#>  [8] "H18117631_0"                                                                           
#>  [9] "R1_0"                                                                                  
#> [10] "Maa_1240111711220682016_W3367"                                                         
#> [11] "T1_0"                                                                                  
#> [12] "V74_0_1_010_aa081200081259_aa081600081859_aa082100095659_aa095700101159_aa101300105059"
#> [13] "H18121405_0"                                                                           
#> [14] "R1_0"                                                                                  
#> [15] "Mab_2467211713110643835_W4500"                                                         
#> [16] "T1_0"                                                                                  
#> [17] "T2_0"                                                                                  
#> [18] "V62_0_1_010_090500092459_100500101059_101100101659_140700140859_141100141359"          
#> [19] "H71811763_0"                                                                           
#> [20] "R1_0"                                                                                  
#> [21] "Maa_5325411210120486554_W2455"                                                         
#> [22] "Mab_5325411210110485554_W2872"                                                         
#> [23] "T1_0"                                                                                  
#> [24] "T2_0"                                                                                  
#> [25] "T3_0"                                                                                  
#> [26] "T4_0"


# write back the updated data
# writeLines(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [**dplyr**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) solution that uses a [`left_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html)...but otherwise relies exclusively on **vectorized operations**, which are significantly [more efficient than looping](https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/) over large datasets.

While the code might *appear* lengthy, this is simply a formatting choice: the sake of clarity, I use

```
foo(
  arg_1 = bar,
  arg_2 = baz,
  # ...
  arg_n = qux
)
```

rather than the one-liner `foo(bar, baz, qux)`.  Also for the sake of clarity, I will elaborate on the line

```
    # Map each row to its house ID.
    House_id = data[row_number()[target][cumsum(target)]],
```

in the **Details** section.

## Solution

Given a file like `subset.txt` reproduced here

```
H18105265_0
R1_0
Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959
H18117631_0
R1_0
Maa_1240111711220682016_W123650.80
T1_0
V74_0_1_010_aa081200081259_aa081600081859_aa082100095659_aa095700101159_aa101300105059
H18121405_0
R1_0
Mab_2467211713110643835_W923650.80
T1_0
T2_0
V62_0_1_010_090500092459_100500101059_101100101659_140700140859_141100141359
H71811763_0
R1_0
Maa_5325411210120486554_W923650.80
Mab_5325411210110485554_W723650.80
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
T4_0
```

and a reference dataset like `df` reproduced here

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~House_id,   ~id, ~new_weight,
   18105265, "Mab",        4567,
   18117631, "Maa",        3367,
   18121405, "Mab",        4500,
   71811763, "Maa",        2455,
   71811763, "Mab",        2872
)
```

the following solution

```
# For manipulating data.
library(dplyr)


# ...
# Code to generate your reference 'df'.
# ...



# Specify the filepath.
text_filepath <- "subset.txt"

# Define the textual pattern for each data item we want, where the relevant
# values are divided into their own capture groups.
regex_house_id <- "(H)(\\d+)(_)(\\d)"
regex_weighted_label <- "(M[a-z]{2,})(_)(\\d+)(_W)(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"



# Read the textual data (into a dataframe).
data.frame(data = readLines(text_filepath)) %>%

  # Transform the textual data.
  mutate(
    # Target (TRUE) the identifying row (house ID) for each (contiguous) group.
    target = grepl(
      # Use the textual pattern for house IDs.
      pattern = regex_house_id,
      x = data
    ),

    # Map each row to its house ID.
    House_id = data[row_number()[target][cumsum(target)]],

    # Extract the underlying numeric ID from the house ID.
    House_id = gsub(
      pattern = regex_house_id,
      # The numeric ID is in the 2nd capture group.
      replacement = "\\2",
      x = House_id
    ),

    # Treat the numeric ID as a number.
    House_id = as.numeric(House_id),



    # Target (TRUE) the weighted labels.
    target = grepl(
      # Use the textual pattern for weighted labels.
      pattern = regex_weighted_label,
      x = data
    ),

    # Extract the ID from (only) the weighted labels.
    id = if_else(
      target,
      gsub(
        pattern = regex_weighted_label,
        # The ID is in the 1st capture group.
        replacement = "\\1",
        x = data
      ),
      # For any data that is NOT a weighted label, give it a blank (NA) ID.
      as.character(NA)
    ),

    # Extract from (only) the weighted labels everything else but the weight.
    rest = if_else(
      target,
      gsub(
        pattern = regex_weighted_label,
        # Everything is in the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th capture groups; ignoring the ID
        # (1st) and the weight (5th).
        replacement = "\\2\\3\\4",
        x = data
      ),
      # For any data that is NOT a weighted label, make it blank (NA) for
      # everything else.
      as.character(NA)
    )
  ) %>%

  # Link (JOIN) each weighted label to its new weight; with blanks (NAs) for
  # nonmatches.
  left_join(df, by = c("House_id", "id")) %>%

  # Replace (only) the weighted labels, with their updated values.
  mutate(
    data = if_else(
      target,
      # Generate the updated value by splicing together the original components
      # with the new weight.
      paste0(id, rest, new_weight),
      # For data that is NOT a weighted label, leave it unchanged.
      data
    )
  ) %>%

  # Extract the column of updated values.
  .$data %>%

  # Overwrite the original text with the updated values.
  writeLines(con = text_filepath)
```

will transform your textual data and update the original file.

## Result

The original file (here `subset.txt`) will now contain the updated information:

```
H18105265_0
R1_0
Mab_3416311514210525745_W4567
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
V64_0_2_010_ab171900171959
H18117631_0
R1_0
Maa_1240111711220682016_W3367
T1_0
V74_0_1_010_aa081200081259_aa081600081859_aa082100095659_aa095700101159_aa101300105059
H18121405_0
R1_0
Mab_2467211713110643835_W4500
T1_0
T2_0
V62_0_1_010_090500092459_100500101059_101100101659_140700140859_141100141359
H71811763_0
R1_0
Maa_5325411210120486554_W2455
Mab_5325411210110485554_W2872
T1_0
T2_0
T3_0
T4_0
```

## Details

### The Regex

The text manipulation relies on simply the base functionality of [`grepl()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/grep.html) (to identify matches) and [`gsub()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/grep.html) (to extract components).  We divide each of our textual patterns `regex_house_id` and `regex_weighted_label` into their components, as distinguished by [capture groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) in regular expressions:

```
#      The "H" prefix.      The "_" separator.
#                  | |      | |
regex_house_id <- "(H)(\\d+)(_)(\\d)"
#                     |    |   |   |
#  The digits following "H".   The "0" suffix (or any digit).
```

```
#                                The digits after the 'id'.
#   The 'id': "M" then 2 small letters.   |    |    The weight (possibly a decimal).
#                          |          |   |    |    |              |
regex_weighted_label <-   "(M[a-z]{2,})(_)(\\d+)(_W)(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"
#                                      | |      |  |
#                       The "_" separator.      The "_" separator and "W" prefix before weight.
```

We can use `grepl(pattern = regex_weighted_label, x = my_strings)` to check which strings in the vector `my_strings` match the format for a weighted label (like `"Mab_3416311514210525745_W923650.80"`).

We can also use `gsub(pattern = regex_weighted label, replacement = "\\5", my_labels)` to extract the weights (the **5**th capture group) from a vector `my_labels` of labels in that format.

### The Mapping

Found within the first [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) statement, the line

```
    # Map each row to its house ID.
    House_id = data[row_number()[target][cumsum(target)]],
```

might appear mystifying.  However, it is simply a [classic arithmetic trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152086) (also employed by [@mnist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8107362/mnist) in their [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275094)) to index contiguous values as groups.

The code `cumsum(target)` scans over the `target` column, which (at this point in the workflow) has logical values (`TRUE FALSE FALSE ...`) indicating whether (`TRUE`) or not (`FALSE`) the text line is a house ID (like `"H18105265_0"`). When it hits a `TRUE` (numerically a `1`), it increments its running total, while `FALSE` (numerically a `0`) leaves the total unchanged.

Since the textual `data` column

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |------------ ...
  "H18105265_0" "R1_0" ...                 "H18117631_0" "R1_0" ...           "H18121405_0" ...
```

has given us the logical `target` column

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
```

these values (`TRUE` and `FALSE`) are coerced to numeric (`1` and `0`)

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  1    0     0     0     0     0     0     1    0     0     0     0     0     1    0     ...
```

to yield the `cumsum()` here:

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  1    1     1     1     1     1     1     2    2     2     2     2     2     3    3     ...
```

Notice now we've mapped each row to its "group number". So much for `cumsum(target)`.

Now for `row_number()[target]`!  In effect, [`row_number()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html) simply "indexes" each position (row)

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  1             2      ...                 8             9      ...           13         ...
```

in the `data` column (or any other column):

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |------------ ...
  "H18105265_0" "R1_0" ...                 "H18117631_0" "R1_0" ...           "H18121405_0" ...
```

So subscripting those indices by `target`

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  TRUE           FALSE ...                  TRUE          FALSE ...           TRUE       ...
```

selects only those positions with house IDs:

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  1                                         8                                 13         ...
```

So if we take that result for `row_number()[target]`

```
# House ID: 1st 2nd 3rd ...
# Position:
            1   8   13  ...
```

and subscript it by `cumsum(target)`

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  1    1     1     1     1     1     1     2    2     2     2     2     2     3    3     ...
```

we map each row to the position (in `data`) of its house ID:

```
# |-------------- Group 1 ---------------| |----------- Group 2 ------------| |--------- ...
  1    1     1     1     1     1     1     8    8     8     8     8     8     13   13    ...
```

This is the outcome of `row_number()[target][cumsum(target)]`.

Finally, when we subscript `data` by these (repeated) positions of its house IDs, we get the `House_id` column

```
# |----------------- Group 1 -----------------| |----------------- Group 2 -----------------| |-------------------------- ...
  "H18105265_0" "H18105265_0" ... "H18105265_0" "H18117631_0" "H18117631_0" ... "H18117631_0" "H18121405_0" "H18121405_0" ...
```

where each value in `data` is mapped to the house ID of its group.

Thanks to this `House_id` column

```
House_id = data[row_number()[target][cumsum(target)]]
```

next to our `data` column, we can map (`left_join()`) the `id`s in `df` to their corresponding textual `data`.