# Set a value if there is an increase of more than 1 in a column between rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below:

```
RecordID <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
row.number <- c(1,2,10,11,12,45,46)
df <- data.frame(RecordID, row.number)
df$frame.change =1
```

I want the value in frame.change to increase by 1 from the previous row if there is an increase in row.number of more than 1 from the previous row. I am trying the following code but it doesn't work:

```
for( i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$frame.change[i] <- if( (df$frame.change[i] - df$frame.change[i-1]) <1 ){df$frame.change[i-1] }else{ df$frame.change[i-1] +1 }
  cat("-")
}
```

It doesn't need to be done within a for loop and I presume lapply will be the solution but I can't seem to get this to work.

Help appreciated

Comment: `df$frame.change <- cumsum(c(1,diff(df$row.number) > 1))`

Comment: Perhaps a more canonical Q&A on the very useful `cumsum(diff(...` method: [How to partition a vector into groups of regular, consecutive sequences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/how-to-partition-a-vector-into-groups-of-regular-consecutive-sequences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `cumsum` and `diff` is all you need:

```
df$frame.change <- cumsum(c(1, diff(df$row.number) > 1))
```

which gives:

```
> df
  RecordID row.number frame.change
1        a          1            1
2        b          2            1
3        c         10            2
4        d         11            2
5        e         12            2
6        f         45            3
7        g         46            3
```

Comment: Thanks Jaap, much appreciated