# subset data frame within group in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame like this

```
ID <- c(1)
Rank <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
Val <- c(10,20,30,40,50)

df <- data.frame(ID,Rank,Val)
df

  ID Rank Val
1  1    1  10
2  1    2  20
3  1    3  30
4  1    1  40
5  1    2  50
```

Within each ID, how to subset the dataframe such that I have two different frames

```
df1:

  ID Rank Val
1  1    1  10
2  1    2  20
3  1    3  30

df2:

  ID Rank Val
4  1    1  40
5  1    2  50
```

The total length of each ID could vary. Hence sometimes I could have rank like `1,2,1,2`. In this case, the two frames will be (1,2) and (1,2)

Comment: Try with `split` ie. `split(df, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$Rank) < 0)))`

Comment: yes that works, though it returns a list but that still is good for me

Comment: akrun can you please post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: A canonical post for the `cumsum(...diff(...) <condition>)` idiom: [How to partition a vector into groups of regular, consecutive sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/how-to-partition-a-vector-into-groups-of-regular-consecutive-sequences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create the `f` based on taking the difference between adjacent elements of 'Rank' column, create a logical `vector`, convert it to numeric with `cumsum` and `split` based on that

```
split(df, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$Rank) < 0)))
```