# Identify groups of n consecutive numbers in a data.table field in a group

Tags: r, data.table

This data.table shows the months of year attended by students.

```
DT = data.table(
 Student = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
             3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
 Month   = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12,
             2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10,
             1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

DT
    Student Month
 1:       1     1
 2:       1     2
 3:       1     3
 4:       1     5
 5:       1     6
 6:       1     7
 7:       1     8
 8:       1    11
 9:       1    12
10:       2     2
11:       2     3
12:       2     4
13:       2     5
14:       2     7
15:       2     8
16:       2     9
17:       2    10
18:       3     1
19:       3     2
20:       3     3
21:       3     5
22:       3     6
23:       3     7
24:       3     8
25:       3     9
```

I want to identify periods of three consecutive months (identified by the first month in the period). This is visualization of the data table and the eligible periods.

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12


1      *   *   *       *   *   *   *           *   *
       [-------]       [-------]
                           [-------]                           


2          *   *   *   *       *   *   *   *
           [-------]           [-------]
               [-------]           [-------]


3      *   *   *       *   *   *   *   *      
       [-------]       [-------]
                           [-------]
                               [-------]
```

Desired output:

```
id   First_month_in_the_period 

1    1
1    5
1    6
2    2
2    3
2    7
2    8
3    1
3    5
3    6
3    7
```

Looking for data.table (or dplyr) solutions.

Comment: Just a doubt, why is 1, 2, 3 not consecutive for the id 1

Comment: They are: the desired output includes id = 1 with Month = 1. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the logic correct.  In the desired output, 2, 3 rows are removed, similarly 7 is removed fro 'id' 1.  May be if you can describe more clearly

Comment: My apologies! I should've made it clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

DT2 <- DT %>%
  arrange(Student, Month) %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  # Create sequence of 3
  mutate(Seq = map(Month, ~seq.int(.x, .x + 2L))) %>%
  # Create a flag to show if the sequence match completely with the Month column 
  mutate(Flag = map_lgl(Seq, ~all(.x %in% Month))) %>%
  # Filter the Flag for TRUE
  filter(Flag) %>%
  # Remove columns
  select(-Seq, -Flag) %>%
  ungroup()

DT2
# # A tibble: 11 x 2
#    Student Month
#      <dbl> <dbl>
#  1       1     1
#  2       1     5
#  3       1     6
#  4       2     2
#  5       2     3
#  6       2     7
#  7       2     8
#  8       3     1
#  9       3     5
# 10       3     6
# 11       3     7
```

Comment: Truly a great answer!

Answer (score 7):

Use [standard method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/how-to-partition-a-vector-into-groups-of-regular-consecutive-sequences) (`cumsum...diff...condition`) to identify runs of consecutive values, which then is used as grouping variable together with 'Student'. Within each group, create sequence based on length of each run and add to first month.

```
DT[ , .(start = if(.N >= 3) Month[1] + 0:(.N - 3)),
    by = .(Student, r = cumsum(c(1L, diff(Month) > 1)))]
#     Student r start
#  1:       1 1     1
#  2:       1 2     5
#  3:       1 2     6
#  4:       2 3     2
#  5:       2 3     3
#  6:       2 4     7
#  7:       2 4     8
#  8:       3 4     1
#  9:       3 5     5
# 10:       3 5     6
# 11:       3 5     7
```

Equivalent `dplyr` alternative:

```
DT %>% 
  group_by(Student, r = cumsum(c(1L, diff(Month) > 1))) %>%
  summarise(list(data.frame(start = if(n() >= 3) Month[1] + 0:(n() - 3)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest()

# # A tibble: 11 x 3
# # Groups:   Student [3]
#       Student     r start
#         <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#     1       1     1     1
#     2       1     2     5
#     3       1     2     6
#     4       2     3     2
#     5       2     3     3
#     6       2     4     7
#     7       2     4     8
#     8       3     4     1
#     9       3     5     5
#    10       3     5     6
#    11       3     5     7
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution, its uses the group by that data.table provides,

```
seqfun <- function(month) {
    n <- length(month)
    tmp <- data.table(a=month[1:(n-2)],b=month[2:(n-1)],c=month[3:n])
    month[which(apply(tmp,1,function(x){all(c(1,1)==diff(x))}))]}

Result <- DT[,seqfun(Month), by=Student]
names(Result) <- c("Student","Month")
```

```
> Result
    Student Month
 1:       1     1
 2:       1     5
 3:       1     6
 4:       2     2
 5:       2     3
 6:       2     7
 7:       2     8
 8:       3     1
 9:       3     5
10:       3     6
11:       3     7
```

Essentially it takes the groups month vector, creates 3 vectors to compare `diff`s and checks if both `diff`s are a distance of 1. If so, the original month vector's index is returned.

A little bit of detail. Suppose we have,

```
month <- c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,11,12)
```

and we compute the `tmp` `data.table` (Note: you can also use the `rollapply` function in `zoo` to create a similar table, I'll show this at the very bottom)

```
   a  b  c
1: 1  2  3
2: 2  3  5
3: 3  5  6
4: 5  6  7
5: 6  7  8
6: 7  8 11
7: 8 11 12
```

When we take the `diff` across rows, we get,

```
> apply(tmp,1,function(x){all(c(1,1)==diff(x))})
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The true values are the indices we are interested in.

As mentioned above, using the `zoo` library's `rollapply` we could have,

```
> apply(c(1,1)==rollapply(month,width=3,FUN=diff),1,all)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

to get a boolean vector of the indices we are interested for a specific Student.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base` R solution that creates a function that can be applied to a `data.table`:

```
cons3fun<-function(x,n){

              consec.list<-split(x,cumsum(c(1,diff(x)!=1))) #Splits into list based on consecutive numbers

              min.len.seq<-consec.list[which(sapply(consec.list,length)>(n-1))] #Selects only the list elements >= to n

              seq.start<-lapply(min.len.seq,function(i) i[1:(length(i)-(n-1))]) #Extracts the first number of each sequence of n

              return(as.vector(unlist(seq.start))) #Returns result as a vector
}
```

Note that this function will allow you to change the number of consecutive numbers you are looking for fairly easily. Here you would use `n=3`.  Then you can apply this function using either `data.table` or `dplyr`.  I will use `data.table` since you used one.

```
DT[,cons3fun(Month,3),by=.(Student)]
```

Hope you find this useful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach using `tidyverse`:

```
> as_tibble(DT) %>%
      arrange(Student, Month) %>%
      group_by(Student) %>%
      # create an identifier for the start of the sequence
      mutate(seq_id = ifelse(row_number() == 1 | Month - lag(Month) > 1,
                             letters[row_number()], NA)) %>%
      fill(seq_id) %>%
      # add another grouping level (sequence identifier)
      group_by(Student, seq_id) %>%
      # only keep data with attendance in 3 or more consecutive months 
      filter(length(seq_id) > 2) %>%
      # n consecutive months => n - 2 periods
      slice(1:(n() - 2)) %>%
      # clean up
      ungroup() %>%
      select(Student, Month)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   Student Month
#    <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1     1
#2       1     5
#3       1     6
#4       2     2
#5       2     3
#6       2     7
#7       2     8
#8       3     1
#9       3     5
#10      3     6
#11      3     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` approach...

```
#first, clculate the difference between months, by student.
ans <- DT[, diff := shift( Month, type = "lead" ) - Month ), by = .(Student)]
#then filter rows that are at the start of 2 consecutive differences of 1
#also, drop the temporary diff-column
ans[ diff == 1 & shift( diff, type = "lead" ) == 1,][, diff := NULL][]
```

voila

```
#    Student Month
# 1:       1     1
# 2:       1     5
# 3:       1     6
# 4:       2     2
# 5:       2     3
# 6:       2     7
# 7:       2     8
# 8:       3     1
# 9:       3     5
# 10:      3     6
# 11:      3     7
```