# Calculating median in each consecutive run

Tags: r, rle

I have a `data.frame` as below;

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(2,3,5,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16),
             value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
> df
   ID value
1   2     1
2   3     2
3   5     3
4   8     4
5   9     5
6  10     6
7  12     7
8  14     8
9  15     9
10 16    10
11 17    11
```

Here, I would like to obtain the list of medians when `ID` is consecutive. For example, `ID` in the first two row shows `2,3`, which is consecutive. In this case, I would like to obtain the median of `value` in the first two rows, which should be

```
> median(c(1,2))
[1] 1.5
```

Then, next consecutive `ID` are `8,9,10`, `14,15,16,17`. The corresponding medians should be

```
> median(c(4,5,6))
[1] 5
> median(c(8,9,10,11))
[1] 9.5
```

Then, what I finally want is the `data.frame` like below

```
   ID   median
1   2    1.5
2   8    5
3  14    9.5
```

I wonder `rle` might be useful, but I am not sure how I implement this.
Do you have any suggestion to implement this? I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: You may create a grouping variable as described here: [Create grouping variable for consecutive sequences and split vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/create-grouping-variable-for-consecutive-sequences-and-split-vector). (the split is not needed). Then run your favorite 'by-group' function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Although I used the method from another answer, but the url you provided is very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome! As you see, the same idiom is used in the answer below: `cumsum(...diff(`. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I had found that point! Thank you very much. Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  if (.N > 1) data.table(ID = min(ID), value = median(value)),
  .(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(ID) != 1)))
][
  ,
  grp := NULL
][]
```

which gives

```
   ID value
1:  2   1.5
2:  8   5.0
3: 12   9.0
```

Comment: This works! I have not used data.table before, and I will learn it more because it looks very useful.