# Group rows by time interval in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, lubridate

I have the following part of my data:

```
    test <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "date_time"            , "automatic", "validate" |
     "2020-12-01 00:34:58", "sombra"   , "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 00:34:59", "organismo", "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 00:35:00", "partes"   , "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 00:35:01", "sombra"   , "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 00:36:02", "organismo", "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 00:36:03", "organismo", "partes"   |
     "2020-12-01 06:35:58", "sombra"   , "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 06:35:59", "partes"   , "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 06:36:00", "sombra"   , "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 06:36:01", "sombra"   , "partes"   |
     "2020-12-01 06:37:15", "organismo", "sombra"   |
     "2020-12-01 06:37:16", "partes"   , "sombra"   )
```

The column date_time corresponds to date (year, month and day) and time (hour, minute and second). This column has time values (not all here) for each second for every 3 minutes, after the third minute the data (next row) starts +-30 minutes later (again, not all data here).

I would create a column called cycle that gets the first date_time after this interval of +-30min and repeat this value until the next cycle of 3 minutes.

output desired for this data:

```
wrapr::build_frame(
   "date_time"            , "automatic", "validate", "cycle"               |
     "2020-12-01 00:34:58", "sombra"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 00:34:58" |
     "2020-12-01 00:34:59", "organismo", "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 00:34:58" |
     "2020-12-01 00:35:00", "partes"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 00:34:58" |
     "2020-12-01 00:35:01", "sombra"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 00:34:58" |
     "2020-12-01 00:36:02", "organismo", "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 00:34:58" |
     "2020-12-01 00:36:03", "organismo", "partes"  , "2020-12-01 00:34:58" |
     "2020-12-01 06:35:58", "sombra"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 06:35:58" |
     "2020-12-01 06:35:59", "partes"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 06:35:58" |
     "2020-12-01 06:36:00", "sombra"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 06:35:58" |
     "2020-12-01 06:36:01", "sombra"   , "partes"  , "2020-12-01 06:35:58" |
     "2020-12-01 06:37:15", "organismo", "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 06:35:58" |
     "2020-12-01 06:37:16", "partes"   , "sombra"  , "2020-12-01 06:35:58" )
```

Thanks all

Comment: why does a new cycle start at `06:35:58`, one minute after the previous one?

Comment: Because is the first time after an interval (> 30min after previous time)

Comment: [Create grouping variable for consecutive sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/create-grouping-variable-for-consecutive-sequences-and-split-vector) and grab the first time by group.